# Bypassing SSL certificate verification using Flask, gunicorn, gevent

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, gevent

I am getting CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED errors because when I make a openurl request with urllib, it is checking the https certificates, and as my endpoint is using a self signed certificate (using our companies internal CA), they are obviously failing the verification check.

I know I can use requests, or create my own context, however it is a third party library that is making the call, and I can't change how that happens. As its just an internal app, I couldn't care less about the verification, so I am just happy to skip verification on all https requests.

The internet suggests the easiest way to do this is, is to create an env variable `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0`, or to monkey patch the ssl library with

```
# Set prior to pretty much everything

import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

So this is working fine until I go to run things using gunicorn which is configured to use gevent workers. I am also stuck using python 2.7.18

Wondering if anyone has any solutions, or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of headache I have worked out the problem arises because when gunicorn spins up the gevent workers, they call `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` after my app is initialised. Unfortunately this overwrites my monkey patches (done in my app init) and resets things.

I thought this should still be ok, because the `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0` is still set, and the SSL lib should see that, and ignore verification. HOWEVER! the SSL lib that gevent replaces (monkey patches) the system one with is an old version and it doesn't look for the ENV variable.

So, I needed a way to further monkey patch (`ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`) AFTER the gevent monkey patching!

Fortunately gunicorn provides a hook to do this, and we can setup a function in the config file to do it for us. My gunicorn config looks something like this:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8080'
accesslog = 'gunicornaccess.log'
errorlog = 'gunicornerror.log'
loglevel = 'DEBUG'
timeout = 240000
pidfile = 'gunicorn.pid'
debug = True
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = 8
threads = 4

def post_worker_init(worker):
   import ssl
   ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

I mean monkey patching is bad idea in general, but this is the only way I could get it work. Hopefully this saves someone else the headache I went through to get here.